# Scrolling whole bigger element from the parent smaller element with using position:absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have `canvas` and `div` which has smaller size than `canvas`.

Upper one can't scroll the whole image.

Lower one can scroll the whole image.

The difference is using `absolute`.

However I want to use `absolute` (for centering and layering multiple canvas)

How can I scroll whole image with `absolute`?

```js
var ctx_test1 = $('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
var ctx_test2 = $('canvas')[1].getContext('2d');

var chara = new Image();
chara.src = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/yr8ehzbdwm0csc7/Madeira_-_Entrance_to_Town%2C_c._1900.jpg?dl=0";

chara.onload = () => { 
      ctx_test1.clearRect(0, 0,240,157);
      ctx_test1.drawImage(chara,0,0,240,157);
      ctx_test2.clearRect(0, 0,240,157);
      ctx_test2.drawImage(chara,0,0,240,157);   
 }
```

```css
#whole1{
border:1px solid;
  width:120px;
  height:78px;
  overflow:scroll;
  position:relative;
}
#whole2{
border:1px solid;
  width:120px;
  height:78px;
  overflow:scroll;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/yr8ehzbdwm0csc7/Madeira_-_Entrance_to_Town%2C_c._1900.jpg?dl=0">
<div id="whole1">
<canvas id="test"
style="width:240px;height:157px;
position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%, -50%)"
width="240px" height="157px"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="whole2">
<canvas id="test2"
style="width:240px;height:157px;"
width="240px" height="157px"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
```